# How to fix browser console errors for WordPress site

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

Hi while inspecting my website in chrome browser I am getting some console errors I don't have idea how fix this pls help me on this issue.

[image: Screenshot of errors]

I tried to check from where this error is coming but I am not sure why these errors showing I want to fix these errors so when I click inspect in chrome it will not show under console tab

Comment: They're mostly warnings rather than critical errors so you don't need to panic, you have time to resolve them. If you look on the right hand side of each line it tells you what code the message originated from or was triggered by

Answer (score 1):

1. The font request is malformed. The correct request URL is `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost&display=swap`.
2. As the error says, the Google Maps JavaScript API has been loaded without a callback. See https://goo.gle/js-api-loading.
3. `-webkit-backdrop-filter` may only be available in some browsers, so there's nothing to worry about. The error says that there might be a missing plugin, so check that.
4. `https://revivesunnah.com/cart.json` does not exist. Create the file.